# Is there a way for a class to access fields in classes that inherit from it using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

What I'm trying to do is have a class that I can inherit from and be able to track changes to properties.

I have this base class called TrackedEntity.

I then create another class TestEntity that inherits from TrackedEntity.

On my TestEntity class I have marked one of my fields with an attribute that I called CompareValues.

TrackedEntity

```cs
  public class TrackedEntity {
        public void GetCompareValues<T> () {

            var type = typeof (T);
            var properties = type.GetProperties ();

            foreach (var property in properties) {

              var attribute = (CompareValues[]) property.GetCustomAttributes 
                                             (typeof(CompareValues), false);

              var hasAttribute = Attribute.IsDefined (property, typeof 
                                   (CompareValues));

            }
        }
    }
```

TestEntity

```cs
public class TestEntity : TrackedEntity
    {
        public int one { get; set; }
        [CompareValues]
        public int two { get; set; }
        public int three { get; set; }
    }
```

CompareValues attribute:

```cs
 [AttributeUsage ( AttributeTargets.Property | 
                      AttributeTargets.Field,
                      Inherited = true)]
    public class CompareValues : Attribute {
        public CompareValues () { }
    }
```

I can then do this

```cs
var test  = new TestEntity ();
test.GetCompareValues<TestEntity> ();
```

In my GetCompareValues method I can find which fields in TestEntity use my CompareValues attribute.

I am trying to find a way to access the value of the fields that have the CompareValues attribute so that I can track the changes and log information about it.

If there is any other way to get this done by using another method please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: `GetType()` returns the actual runtime type of the object, even when you call it on a reference to a base class. There would be little point in it otherwise.

Comment: Your question isn't written very clearly. Your title says you want to get fields, but the code you posted involves properties. Regardless, getting the fields or properties of a specific object is a well-known, well-documented operation, and questions related to that have been answered literally hundreds of times on Stack Overflow. See marked duplicates for examples.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

You´re almost there. All you need to do is to get the properties value on the current instance - the instance on which you´ve called the method:

```
if(hasAttribute)
{
    var value = property.GetValue(this, null);
}
```

Apart from this you won´t need generics here. Just use this:

```
var type = this.GetType();
```

which returns `TestEntity` in case of the instance being of your derived type.

Comment: Thank you so much!